# How to say... match when field is a number... in mongodb?

Tags: python, mongodb

So I have a field called 'city' in my results...the results are corrupted, some times it's an actual name, sometimes it's a number. The following code displays all the records...

```
db.zips.aggregate([{$project : {city:{$substr:["$city",0,1]}}},{$sort : {city : 1}} ])
```

I need to modify this line to display only the records with a city who has a name that is a number (2,3,4, etc)....I think I can use '$match', but how?

```
db.zips.aggregate([{$project : {city:{$substr:["$city",0,1]}}},{$sort : {city : 1}}, {$match:{???what_to_say_here???} ])
```

How to say 'match when city is a number'?

the out put I get looks like this...

```
    {
        "city" : "A",
        "_id" : "04465"
    },
    {
        "city" : "1",
        "_id" : "02821"
    },
    {
        "city" : "0",
        "_id" : "04689"
    }
```

I'm trying to display only the records with a numeric string...this is related to a larger "homework" problem but I can't even get to the actual homework question until I get past this point.

Comment: fortunately, the homework is not "match when field is a number".

Comment: @AndredeFrere the point of the free online 'alpha' (not even beta) course is to get more coders involved in using the software....don't be offended if we seek help in questions that could use a little adjusting for accessibility by non current mongoDB experts.

Comment: No offense taken and apologies if any has been given, just didn't want anyone to get carried away and give out actual homework answers on SO.

Comment: fair enough....well my time has expired on this HW question and I can see the answer now. :( So let me ask...how do I do a "db.zips.remove()" on the results of the collection found via the answer below (last answer)???

Comment: the easiest way would be to simply remove with a regex: `db.zips.remove({ city : /^[0-9]/})`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19618/discussion-between-thefonso-and-andre-de-frere)

Comment: This one is also homework in education.mongodb.com dba courses, so the answers was really helpfull

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use the [`$type`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/type/) operator in your `$match`:

```javascript
db.zips.aggregate([
    {$project : {city:{$substr:["$city",0,1]}}},
    {$sort : {city : 1}}, 
    {$match: {city: {$type: 16}}}      // city is a 32-bit integer
]);
```

There isn't a single type value for number so you need to know which type of number you have:

```javascript
32-bit integer   16
64-bit integer   18
Double           1
```

Or use an `$or` operator to match all types of numbers:

```javascript
db.zips.aggregate([
    {$project : {city:{$substr:["$city",0,1]}}},
    {$sort : {city : 1}}, 
    {$match: {$or: [{city: {$type: 1}}, {city: {$type: 16}}, {city: {$type: 18}}]}}
]);
```

Or even use `$not` to match all docs where `city` is not a string:

```javascript
db.zips.aggregate([
    {$project : {city:{$substr:["$city",0,1]}}},
    {$sort : {city : 1}}, 
    {$match: {city: {$not: {$type: 2}}}}      // city is not a string
]);
```

**UPDATED**

To match all docs where `city` is a numeric string you can use a regular expression:

```javascript
db.zips.aggregate([
    {$project : {city:{$substr:["$city",0,1]}}},
    {$sort : {city : 1}}, 
    {$match: {city: /^\d.*$/}}      // city is all digits
]);
```

Comment: Hmmm, all I get back is "{ "result" : [ ], "ok" : 1 }"....I'm hoping to actually display the result back

Comment: @thefonso When you say city is a number, I was assuming it was a numeric type; did you just mean that it was a numeric string?

Comment: ah..yes it is a numeric string.

Comment: @thefonso OK, I added that case to the answer.

Comment: these seem to work but I'm not getting the displayed output I was hoping for, just a results ok line. So maybe 'match' is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: The last one was it! Thank you kind sir! Now I can work on the other three things needed to actually answer the homework question.

Answer (score 19):

Why not to use $regex?

```
db.zips.aggregate([
    {$project : {city:{$substr:["$city",0,1]}}},
    {$sort : {city : 1}}, 
    {$match: {city:{$regex:'[0-9]'}}}
])
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply use:

```
db.zips.aggregate([
{$match: {
    'city': { $regex: '^[0-9].*'}
}}])
```

This work fine for me!

Comment: Also `{ $match: {city: /^\d+/} }`. I think this is actually the most sane solution, as it will be able to use an `{city:1}` index.

Answer (score 3):

An easier way to match all docs where `city` is a numeric string is using the property `'0' <= city <= '9'` i.e. your aggregation query becomes:

```
db.zips.aggregate([
    {$project : {city:{$substr:["$city",0,1]}}},
    {$sort : {city : 1}}, 
    {$match: {city: {$gte: '0', $lte: '9'}}}
]);
```

When using JohnnyHK's suggestion of a regex you can save yourself the `$project` stage altogether.

Comment: This is the best answer. It's not brittle, like checking for type code, it's not slow like a regex match. This method would even be able to use an index in some cases, though not in this one.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use an `in` command

```
db.zips.aggregate([     
    {
        $project: {
            first_char: { 
                $substr : ["$city",0,1]
            }, 
            "_id":"$_id"
        } 
    }, 
    {
        $match: {
            first_char: { 
                $in: ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"] 
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Wouldn't `{ $match: { first_char: { $gte: "0", $lte: "9" } } }` be a simpler solution?

Answer (score 1):

you can also try like the following, using regular expression without using $regex

```
db.zips.aggregate([
{$project : { city : { $substr : ["$city",0,1] } }}, 
{$sort : {city : 1}}, 
{$match: { city:/[0-9]/}}
])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
db.zips.aggregate([
    {$project : {city:{$substr:["$city",0,1]},pop:1}},
    {$group:{_id:"$city",sumPop:{$sum:"$pop"}}},
    {$sort : {_id : 1}}, 
    {$match:{_id : {$regex:/\d/}} },
    {$group:{_id:"id",sumPop:{$sum:"$sumPop"}}},
]);
```

Comment: We don't need the sort command, as we are filtering out based on digit.

Answer (score 0):

With the mongodb **4.4** (upcoming), You can use [**`$isNumber`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/isNumber/) pipeline operator to check whether the expression is integer or other BSON type.

```
db.zips.find({ "$expr": { "$anyElementTrue": { "$isNumber": "$city" }}})
```

[**`$isNumber`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/isNumber/) will return true or false corrsoponding to the expression and [**`$anyElementTrue`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/anyElementTrue/) will return the `$match`ed documents.