# Regex under $match doesn't yield results

Tags: mongodb

I'm using this query :

```
db.getCollection('fuelings').aggregate([ 
 {
     $match: {    
                "dateCreated" : {$gte:  "2020-08-12T00:00:00.000Z" ,$lt:  "2020-08-22T12:00:00.000Z"} 
             } 
 }] )
```

Which does yields results as you can see :

[image]

But now I want to add another filter  in `$match` , which filters all `"status" ( from line #9) is a digit` . So I've used regex :

So I've added this :

```
 $match: {  "status":/\d/ ,....
```

But now it yields 0 results :

[image]

**Question:**

Why is it happening?  `\d` is a digit regex. why it doesn't yield results ?

Comment: here is the similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13409386/how-to-say-match-when-field-is-a-number-in-mongodb), i tried its not working for me also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are couple of things missing.

1. You are directly passing regex to `match` but doc says it supports only [read operation query syntax](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match). But you can use aggregate operations under `$expr`
2. To handle that, you should have one of `regex` queries such as `regexFind`
3. But those queries [supports only strings](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/regexFind/#operator-fields)

So you can convert to string using `toString` before matching.

1. [Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2HEUjmK2w9s) - using `find`
2. You can use `$expr` in `$match` - [play](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6xkG7vaDp2o)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        "$regexFind": {
          "input": {
            $toString: "$key"
          },
          "regex": "\\d"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

3. For versions before 4.2 - use `regex`

[play](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5eWCnBXWwC3)

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    $project:{
        key:{
            $toString:
            "$key"} 
    }
}, 
  {
    $match: {
      "key": {
        "$regex": "\\d"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: it shows an error : https://i.imgur.com/Jb1475Z.jpg

Comment: I guess you are using version prior to 4.2. In that case, use $regex - `Prior to MongoDB 4.2, aggregation pipeline can only use the query operator $regex in the $match stage`

Comment: What is your mongo version?

Comment: I dont understand whats going on https://i.imgur.com/bbx7M3E.jpg . why  first pic doesnt yied data ?

Comment: When you project, you need to add what is needed for the next pipeline. Date created has to be added to project.

Comment: @RoyiNamir just use `$addFields` instead of `$project`

Comment: @RoyiNamir here is your final working example https://mongoplayground.net/p/1OKm3eNFAhL

Comment: in above comment @Gibbs explained, in [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/index.html) you need to specify required fields for response, and [$addFeilds](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/index.html) will add new fields together with existing fields.